# Assign specific number to letter

Tags: node.js, numbers, blackjack, letter

I'm working on a little text-based Blackjack game in NodeJS. I've got this array:

```
const ranks = Array('A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K');
```

The game picks a random number from this array and displays it. But, with letters you can't count. In Blackjack, the "J", "Q" and "K" are 10. The A is 1 OR 11.

I still want it to display to the user the letter, but it has to count with 10. So how can I assign this 10 (or 1/11) to the face-cards, but still display the letter.

Comment: Try using a dictionary like so:
`var ranks = {a:1,2:2,3:3,...,j:10,q:10,k:10};`
Then, a an exception in your process to handle the A.

Comment: Or, just use actual numbers internal to your logic, but when you want to display something, change it to A, J, Q or K if it matches one of those numbers with a map or a switch.  Then, the only time you have to do the translation is when you display, not when you're doing game processing.

Comment: It's common for beginning programmers to rely too much on strings. Strings are for people--computers use numbers. Instead of using strings to represent cards and then looking up numbers, use numbers to represent cards and look up strings when needed to talk to humans. In the former case, you'll need a hash object, in the latter case, an array.  In almost every programming language in the world, the latter will be much faster (JavaScript is an exception--its arrays are just hashes in disguise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way that I think of this is to define an array of objects rather than an array of Strings.

```
const ranks = [
{
  actualValue: 11,
  faceValue: 'A'
},
{
  actualValue: 2,
  faceValue: '2'
},
...
];
```

With this data structure you can do your math to get counts and also display whatever you want to display.